# Can budget lines of two agents containing equilibrium allocations be different?

Tags: microeconomics, general-equilibrium, competitive-equilibrium

Consider a pure exchange economy that has two goods and two agents (people). Suppose the initial endowments of person $A$ and $B$ are $(e_x^{A}, e_y^{A})$ and $(e_x^{B}, e_y^{B})$ (resp.) such that $e_i^P \geq 0$.

Is it possible to have (one or more) competitive equilibrium allocations such that the corresponding budget lines of the two agents are not the same?

In other words, if $((x_A^{*}, y_A^{*}), (x_B^{*}, y_B^{*}))$ is a competitive equilibrium allocation and its corresponding price vector is $(p_x^{*}, p_y^{*})$, then can the budget lines $p_x^{*} x_A + p_y^{*} y_A = p_x^{*} e_x^{A} + p_y^{*} e_y^{A}$ and $p_x^{*} x_B + p_y^{*} y_B= p_x^{*} e_x^{B} + p_y^{*} e_y^{B}$ be different?

There's no restriction on the values of the endowments or the prices. I am looking for an example where this is possible.

Comment: 1. Yes, the two budget lines can be totally different, because you are not specifying that you are transforming $B$'s budges line according to the Edgeworth-box coordinate system.

Comment: 2. Have you tried substituting the Edgeworth-box coordinates? E.g., $x_B = e_1^A+e_2^B - x_A$? (Not the best indexig, IMO $e_1^A$ should be $e_x^A$.)

Comment: @Giskard I have changed the indexing as per your suggestions. 1. I don't understand what you mean by Edgeworth-box coordinate system. Everything lies within the Edgeworth box, so the coordinate system is already set accordingly. 2. Yes, and then it is equal. 3. Why is that you say budget lines can be different in 1 and then in 2, you say they are same. Can you please give an example for 1?

Comment: @Giskard I was previously not sure if a case like [this](https://magma.com/d/tpVTUTq2Dk) is possible. But now I realize that the price vector corresponds to a single slope while in this, the slopes of the two budget lines are different. Right?

Comment: Re: 1. and "*Everything lies within the Edgeworth box*": can you please quote the part of your question where you mention that the coordinates are to be understood as an Edgeworth box?

Comment: @Giskard If the agents have endowments, their allocations lie within the Edgeworth box by default, isn't it so? Or is there there something that I am not aware of? Agent $A$'s allocation $(x_A, y_A)$ will always be bounded by $0 \leq x_A \leq e_x^{A} + e_x^{B}$ and $0 \leq y_A \leq e_y^{A} + e_y^{B}$. Similarly, for agent $B$. I think I am not aware of something that you're referring to.

Comment: The Edgeworth-Box is merely an educational tool, a visualization trick. The tuple $(x_A,y_A,x_B,y_B)$ exists originally in $\mathbb{R}^4$, not in the $\mathbb{R}^2$ box. General equilibrium statements are valid without the box. In fact, I think intermediate level general equilibrium books seldom mention the box.

Comment: @Giskard Thanks, though I don't know how any of this answers the original question. Nor do I know what difference it creates when I use the Edgeworth box and when I don't. The tuple $(x_A, y_A, x_B, y_B) = (x_A, y_A, e_x^{A} + e_x^{B} - x_A, e_y^{A} + e_y^{B} - y_A) \cong (x_A, y_A)$ gives us an equivalence from $\mathbb{R}^4$ to the Edgeworth box coordinates for all points that clear the market.